# Path to picture on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm not quite new but still have a few noob questions this is one of them.

I need a path to one of the pictures all ready in my camera roll on my test iphone.  How do I get/find this, not programmatically.  I want to hard code it for testing for file upload so I can trouble shoot.

so

```
filePath:@"/private/var/mobile/Applications/14C39895-E73B-400F-8158-F1F5047A826C/tmp/upload.jpg"
```

should be what:

```
filePath:@"fill in this spot"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the photos directly (unless your app wrote them to the docs folder to begin with -- in which case you would know the path).  You'll need to implement a UIImagePicker to select the photo from your photo album.  The UIImagePicker delegate will then have access to the photo where you can do whatever you want with it(including writing a copy of it to documents).  After the photos been selected once and written to docs, you could then access it in documents on later executions of the app.

The UIImagePicker delegate should implement:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

Then you can write the image to your apps docs folder in that delegate method, something like this:

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/

At that point you could always access the photo in your apps docs folder for upload testing...  You probably need to implement a UIImagePicker for your app anyway, so instead of looking for your test photo, it may be easier to just select from photo album using UIImagePicker and upload directly (cutting out the whole writing/reading from docs folder).

Hope that helps!